# sass child elements order?

Tags: html, css, sass

I just want to add styles for child divs. I did this way and it's working.

```
.summary_boxes {
  .header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .description {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

But my header class and description class is in inside of the other div called content.

Should I mention that class also? Like this way

```
.summary_boxes > content {
  .header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .description {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Which is the correct format?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not simple. It depends on how you would like to scale your CSS. First thing's first. CSS is parsed right to left, not left to right. Many people think that something like this:

```
.container > .left-col .column-heading > div > .final_thing_to_style {
  // styles
}
```

is faster than this:

```
.final_thing_to_style {
 // styles
}
```

The second version is more efficient because CSS is parsed from right to left. The class `final_thing_to_style` is immediately found, and the parser is done.

Let's look at your CSS.

```
.summary_boxes > content {
  .header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .description {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

While adding the immediate child makes your CSS more specific, it's not necessary, and should be omitted. But ask yourself how you'll be using `.header` and `.description`. If this is the only place you'll use these classes, consider something like this instead:

```
.summary_box_header,
.summary_box_description {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you'll need different flavors of `.header` and `.description` in different areas of your web page, this suggestion will make your styles too tightly coupled. You'll end up with a lot of duplication.

To loosen the coupling a bit, you could try something like this:

```
.header {
  .summary_boxes & {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .another_context & {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .yet_another_context & {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

This will create the following CSS:

```
.summary_boxes .header {
  text-align: center;
}

.another_context .header {
  text-align: left;
}

.yet_another_context .header {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Using the parent selector `&`, we can create very readable contexts for our `.header` class. We do add some specificity, but gain readability and flexibility.

With some experimentation, you'll be able to create an appropriate, flexible pattern for your styles.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to specificity (https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). 
The rule is to try to keep the specificity level as low as possible, without having your css rules bleed outside of it's intended use area.

Low specificity adds a lot of benefits, one being reusability, simplicity and lighter files. However if your specificity is too low your rules will start to bleed and interfere with each other.

There's no right or wrong here, it all comes down to the intended use case and future proofing your code. Without the HTML code and some background info on how these classes could be used in the future there is no way of saying what you should or shouldn't do in terms of specificity.

Andy's answer has a few examples but there's of course no limits to all the different ways your code could be structured (or restructured in the future).